# Does the iPhone BLE (Bluetooth 4.1) support non-bondable mode connections?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I have a peripheral (using CSR1010's) that only is able to connect to the iPhone if it advertises with Gap settings "Bondable Mode".  For my application, I don't want the phone to bond to the device, but do still want to pair (have a secure connection).

If I put the server in non-bondable mode, the iPhone drops the connection immediately after pairing is authorized without any action on the peripheral (i.e. it's the iPhone disconnecting).

According to the spec, non-bondable mode only means that regardless of how the connection is established (with/without pairing), the devices should not bond (retain that secure connection after this connection).  I'm wondering if the iPhone actually supports this (spec says it's mandatory to support it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that behavior you mention started to happen in iOS 9. Before that it worked fine. It's not standard behaviour but that's what apple does...

What do you want to achieve anyway? Using pairing without bonding does not add any security at all almost, since ble pairing can easily be decrypted.

Comment: Modifying a bootloader which already authorized pairing, not really a security concern more than a minimal changes concern.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not the issue of whether iPhone support the non-bond-able or not, it is the different device can choose the best security level for itself.

which means each device can choose the high security mode(which request peer device also need high security), or choose the lower one(which means he could not connect to higher security node). Regarding to your concern, if iPhone also *use* the non-bondble mode, that means it is meaning less for the high security level since even low security level device can interact with iPhone.

or we can say iPhone can support the mode that without pairing but does no employ it.